# Is buttercream supposed to be piped straight away?

Tags: butter, cream, piping

It took me a couple of attempts before I properly beat my butter and made fluffy buttercream for my eclairs (the filling is whipped butter plus condensed milk per my recipe). I put it into the fridge, took it out in a while, it got solid. I loaded my pastry bag anyway, the buttercream eventually thawed but was no longer as fluffy, got runnier and began to spil over the bag every other squeeze (I had that problem during previous buttercream attempts). Is buttercream supposed to be piped straight away? Or is there a trick which would allow me to store it until later?

Comment: Not part of the question, but if you have problems with spilling piping bags, that’s a completely different issue we could look into at some point.

Comment: often when you store buttercream, you have to whip it again for a minute or two once you remove it from the fridge.

Comment: @Esther will it be as fluffy?